# turn a list of strings into a list of xyz coordinates python

Tags: python, file, list, drawing, pygame

I have a .dat file that is in the following format:

```
J
   366 -1722   583
   366   356  1783
   866   789  1033
   866 -1289  -167
   366 -1722   583
J
  -500 -1472   150
     0 -1039  -600
     0  1039   600
  -500   606  1350
  -500 -1472   150
```

The numbers are xyz coordinates and the J represents a Jump bit; every time the J occurs I need to lift the pencil and go to the next point to continue drawing.

I want to read this file into a python file and store the values in a list as xyz coordinates so I can draw lines from them using pygame.

So far I can read the file into a list using this code

```
file = open('filename.dat', 'r')
vlist = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

Comment: `file` is a reserved word. Also you need to call `close`, (i.e. `close()`

Comment: thanks i was just using file.dat as an example of the file name.  And forgot to add the ()

Comment: I dont think its actually reserved ... its just shadowing a builtin ... also when you are reading closing doesnt get you much ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley, yeah, it's just good form not to shadow built-ins. I think user2840327 changed the filename and not the variable name. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
points= [list(map(int,v.split())) if v.strip().lower() != "j" else "JUMP" for v in vlist]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but now if i print out what is in the list the J turns into Jump which i want but all the xyz points are now a variation of <map object at 0x0000000002D67438>.  And to my knowledge i can not use this to draw.

Comment: edited ... i assumed you were using python 2 where map returns a list